# Could not find a valid gem 'metaclass'

Tags: ruby, rubygems, gemfile

My test did not run because 'mocha' was missing so I added to my `Gemfile`:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem 'mocha'
```

Then I got:

```
Error installing mocha:
[14:47:00][Step 2/4]    mocha requires metaclass (~> 0.0.1, runtime)
```

So I added to my `Gemfile`:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem 'metaclass'
```

And then I get:

```
Could not find a valid gem 'metaclass' (>= 0) in any repository
```

my `ruby` and `os`:

```
# ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [x86_64-linux]
# cat /etc/centos-release 
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
```

What am I missing please?

Comment: Which ruby do you use, on which system?

Comment: @EricDuminil updated my question with `ruby` version and `os`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby 1.8.7 is your problem. It's been [retired](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2013/06/30/we-retire-1-8-7/) more than 3 years ago.

You need a newer Ruby version (most recent one is 2.4).

It shouldn't be a big problem with [RVM](https://rvm.io/). Here's a [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-2-1-0-on-centos-6-5-using-rvm) for CentOS.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately this is the version the project uses and I cannot change it it's a project in maintenance mode and no one will change that, is there a way to use 'mocha' with that version of ruby?

Comment: You could look at release history, and try to find an old mocha which works with Ruby 1.8.7 : https://github.com/freerange/mocha/releases?after=v0.12.2